# Convert a pdf (having images) to word file (doc, docx) in python

Tags: python, win32com, pdftotext, wps

I have a pdf file with multiple images and I want to convert it to an editable word document.
I use the WPS application for word editing.
I have tried the below code but this opens up the 'supposed converted doc' in pdf format only.

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("kwps.Application")
word.visible = 1

wordObj = word.Documents.Open("D:/Work/python/report.pdf")
wordObj.SaveAs("D:/Work/python/report.docx", FileFormat=16)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure WPS has the ability to convert PDF to Word?

Comment: have you tried `win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")`

Comment: @TimRoberts I got that hint from https://www.796t.com/article.php?id=214666

Comment: @darthbaba Word. Application opens up in MS Word and I use WPS.

Comment: @AmishaSaha Yes, but that hint is specifically for Word, not for WPS.  I would guess that WPS simply does not have the ability to translate PDF files.